# How to keep a variable value?

Tags: java, android

The program is meant to store balance, and add value whenever I enter new income, and decrease the value whenever I enter a new expense. However, when i input an expense, the value of my balance becomes negative, as if the integer Bal resets to 0 whenever I start the expense activity.

```
    //Buttons
    btnExpense = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExpense);
    btnExpense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent expenseIntent = new Intent(Mainmenu.this, expenses.class);
            startActivity(expenseIntent);
        }
    });

    btnIncome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnIncome);
    btnIncome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent incomeIntent = new Intent(Mainmenu.this, Income.class);
            startActivity(incomeIntent);
        }
    });



    Intent startIntent = getIntent();
    Intent RecordExpense = getIntent();
    int Expense = RecordExpense.getIntExtra("intExpense", 0);
    Intent RecordIncome = getIntent();
    int Income = RecordIncome.getIntExtra("intIncome", 0);

    int Bal = startIntent.getIntExtra("intBalance", 0);


        TextView tvResult=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        tvResult.setText(Bal +"");
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("intIncome")) {
            Bal=Bal+Income;

            tvResult.setText(Bal + "");
        }
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("intExpense")) {

            Bal=Bal-Expense;
            tvResult.setText(Bal + "");
        }
```

Whenever I input 10 as Bal, and 5 as expense, i expected 5 to be displayed, but it displayed -5 instead

Comment: It seems that your 'Bal' is a local variable that your are getting from 'startIntent'. After updation, you are not setting back 'Bal' to 'startIntent'. So in 'startIntent' its value is always 0. and every income and expense operation is performed on 0.

Comment: So, any ideas on how to fix it? I am quite new and I need help

Comment: is Intent a custom class or inbuilt. According to standard naming convention, there should be a method like startIntent.setIntExtra("intBalance", Bal);

Comment: Yea, the problem is with the default value. However, changing it to Bal doesn't seem to work. It says variable Bal is not initialized

Comment: No friend, you don't need to change in getIntExtra. Add a new line startIntent.setIntExtra("intBalance", Bal);

Comment: It says can't resolve method setIntExtra

Comment: Is Intent a custom class, if it is an inbuilt class, can you share the package name of Intent class

Comment: package com.example.android.logindemo;

Comment: its seems that this is a custom class, you can define setIntExtra method then

Comment: Intent startIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, Mainmenu.class);
                        int Bal = Integer.parseInt(Balance.getText().toString());
                        startIntent.putExtra("intBalance", Bal);

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your 'Bal' is a local variable that your are getting from 'startIntent'. After updation, you are not setting back 'Bal' to 'startIntent'. So in 'startIntent' its value is always 0. and every income and expense operation is performed on 0.

You need to define a method in Intent class to update the balance in "intBalance". startIntent.setIntExtra("intBalance", Bal);

Comment: what do you mean by this? it says cannot resolve method when i type startIntent.setIntExtra("intBalance", Bal);

Comment: I said, you need to create a new method to set updated Balance in startIntent again. I cannot tell the method body as Intent is your custom class. Please figure it out yourself.